# I need a Major schedule file and inside that i also needed to run a sub schedule file,how can i do that?I tried crontab to schedule major

Tags: python, automation

i am not able to schedule the sub schedule file(run only at once)

```
30 1 * * * python3 majorfile.py
```

the major file is scripted like this

---

```
import datetime
import time
import schedule
if today == some specific date:
    def run1():
        exec(open('sub_file.py').read())
        return schedule.CancelJob
    schedule.every().day.at("5:30").do(run1)
```

(this job is needed to run once)

---

with second the part i am facing issue(in this part also have situations like concurrent events)....it is not running....can anyone help me in this?'''

Answer (score 1):

#### Error:-

- The works pending must be checked in a loop.

#### Code:-

```py
import datetime
from time import sleep
import schedule
def run1():
    exec(open('sub_file.py').read())
    return schedule.CancelJob
schedule.every().day.at("5:30").do(run1) 
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: @Bibhav......Thanks for your help

Comment: If this answers your question then consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I am also like to know about the handling of concurrent events